# What is the spectrum of the ring $R((x))$ of formal Laurent series over a ring $R$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring and $R((x))$ the ring of [formal Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Formal_Laurent_series). The elements in the ring $R((x))$ are series of the form
$$
f = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} a_n x^n,
$$
where ${\displaystyle a_{n}=0}$ for all but finitely many negative indices $n$.

The spectrum of a ring is the set of all prime ideals of in the ring.

What is the spectrum of $R((x))$? Thank you very much.

Edit: Assume that $R$ is a field.

Comment: I’m confused; as you say, the spectrum of $R((x))$ is the collection of all prime ideals in $R((x))$.  Are you looking for a description of these prime ideals in terms of the spectrum of $R$ or something along those lines?

Comment: If you don't impose some restrictive properties on $R$, I doubt that an explicit description of the spectrum exists.

Comment: @AlexM., thank you very much. I edited the post and assume that $R$ is a field.

Comment: @AlecRhea, thank you very much. I edited the post and assume that $R$ is a field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $R$ is a field, then the same page that you link to states that [$R((x))$ is a field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Formal_Laurent_series), too - in fact, it is the field of fractions of the ring $R[[x]]$ of formal series. Since it is a field, its only ideals are $0$ and $R((x))$ - of which, by convention, [only $0$ is considered prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal#Prime_ideals_for_commutative_rings). Therefore, the spectrum of $R((x))$ when $R$ is a field is reduced to a single point.